# calling a a div from another to current page through ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am calling html of div from another page to the page I am currently on. This is the script I am using

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function($))
    {
        $('#add').click(
        function()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'addproducts.php',
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    data=$(data).find('div#addproduct');
                    $('#divTransactional').html(data);
                    alert('Done.');
                }
            });
            //$('#divTransactional').load('addproducts.php #addproducts');
        })
    }
</script>
```

And html

```
<a href="#" id="add">Add Products</a>
<div class="container" id="divTransactional"></div>
```

And here is addproduct.php

```
<div id="addproduct">
        <form>
            <div class="product-form">
                <p class="text-product"></p>
                <div>
                    <a class="add-product" href="#">Add Product</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submitDetails" value="Finish"/>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

Nothing happens. I guess there is something wrong with the script jquery.

Comment: Can you console log data variable before alert , and check what is the output.

Comment: expected expression, got ')'

Comment: Looks like a syntax error, try: $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: I have added addproduct.php

Comment: missing ) after argument list

Comment: $(document).ready(function($)) should be    $(document).ready(function($) also end of script }) instead of }

Comment: If the syntax correction doesn't work I think we need more info about what you're trying to do as I'm not understanding entirely.

Comment: Yess guys it was syntax error! Thank you! If anyone wants to put answer and get it approved then do it fast :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function($)
{
    $('#add').click(
    function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'addproducts.php',
            success: function(data) 
            {
                data=$(data).find('div#addproduct');
                $('#divTransactional').html(data);
                alert('Done.');
            }
        });
        //$('#divTransactional').load('addproducts.php #addproducts');
    })
});
```